# Is It mandatory to check in Bin and Obj files to SVN or any other repository?

Tags: c#, repository, tortoisesvn

I am using SVN as my repository. Is it mandatory to **commit Obj and Bin** files to SVN or other repositories. As per my knowledge those are not required because when we build the solution Bin and Obj files will come automatically. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not only it's **not** mandatory but it's actually bad to commit them.

Comment: So we no need to commit Bin and Obj files right... asking just for confirmation.

Comment: Note that I've seen *badly implemented* build environments that require `bin` to be manually filled with some files (data often, but even native dll in some cases), so in this case those files *could* be checked in (but it would be better to fix the build environment so that this operation is done automatically by the *msbuild*/*visual studio*)

Comment: Thanks @xanatos for the detailed explanation. Now I understand what need to commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely correct. Don't check-in `bin` or `obj` folders. Exclude them from check-in list.

Once source code is taken and build locally those debug files and required dll's will get generated automatically

Comment: Thank you so much for your confirmation.